# Facebook Share Requiring Double Login

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to share some text and an image on Facebook for the currently logged in user's wall (or if a use logs into facebook) and I'm getting prompted twice by facebook to login when a user is not logged in when clicking the below link.  The users wall does get updated but the second prompt to `https://www.facebook.com/login.php` breaks the flow.  If the a user is logged in then it doesn't require a double login.  Any ideas?

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=http://www.cnn.com/">test</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by using the below I was able to accomplish what I intended to with the share.php

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/